# How to Convert Timestamp to more readable Time with String

Tags: javascript

So I'm using Timestamps in Mongoose but the format is this: `2021-12-09T08:35:44.189Z`, but I don't want to show this way, instead what I want is: `9 December 2021`.

What is the approach to it? as I haven't found any.

Answer (score 1):

If you will do it by your self , first you can use `new Date("2021-12-09T08:35:44.189Z")` to get the timeStemp of this date ,and then , use the api:
`getFullYear`、 `getMonth`、`getDate()` to get the year、month and date ，then join it by yourself;

```js
let timeStamp = new Date('2021-12-09T08:35:44.189Z');

let year = timeStamp.getFullYear(),
    month = timeStamp.getMonth(),
    date = timeStam.getDate();
```

or you can also use the third-party like day.js to help you do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to use `moment.js`. One-line solution:

```js
console.log(moment('2021-12-09T08:35:44.189Z').format('D MMMM YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```